# c++ Why do I get "does not name a type" error?

Tags: c++

In my main class I have:

```
#include "main.h"
outPut O;
int main(){
...
}
```

where the main.h file has #include "outPut.h"

the "outPut.h" line has:

```
#ifndef OUTPUT_H
#define OUTPUT_H

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

    #include "properties.h"
    #include "particles.h"

    class outPut{
     public:
      outPut();
      std::ofstream file;
      void show(lipid * l);
    };

    #endif
```

and the outPut.cpp:

```
#include "outPut.h"

outPut::outPut(){
}
```

When I compile this I get the error:

> main.cpp:3: error: ‘outPut’ does not
>   name a type

Why so?

Thanks...

Edit, found it. main.h wasn't saved and the #include "outPut.h" was canceled.

Comment: How do you compile this?

Comment: @Mihran its not a link error so the compilation is likely not needed information.

Comment: g++ followed by all the relevant file (in that case g++ main.cpp outPut.cpp properties.cpp particles.cpp

Comment: I suspect you didn't paste your first file correctly because you have no reference to `outPut` on line 3.

Comment: Are your files in same directory?

Comment: The first file is typed in. I don't mind pasting the original file but it only has a return command and another class I have created (and does work)

Comment: Hey I just saved all this and it compiled fine (I deleted one of the methods you didn't define, thats my only change. And I didn't include two other headers.)

Comment: @Mihran, Thanks, I didn't save the changes to the main.h file....

Answer (score 2):

You need to `#include "outPut.h"` in `main.cpp`.

Comment: I'm still learning C++ myself. Why would #including outPut.h in main.h not be good enough?

Comment: Haha I guess it turned out that my answer was right, better accept it :D

Answer (score 0):

grep for OUTPUT_H in all source files. You might have inadvertently defined the include guard in some other header which is included earlier than outPut.h.

Comment: [avityo@niels src]$ grep OUTPUT_H *
outPut.h:#ifndef OUTPUT_H
outPut.h:#define OUTPUT_H
outPut.h~:#ifndef OUTPUT_H
outPut.h~:#define OUTPUT_H
Nope, everything is fine...

Comment: Well, for some reason #include "main.h" does not include the definition of outPut. If you are using g++ you could compile with -E to see the preprocessor output. That should be informative.